# Using Redis In Kivy Mobile app?

Tags: android, python-2.7, redis, kivy

I have installed redis and redis-py and my code works perfectly fine on desktop as i have redis-server up and running but any idea how i can port the same code on my mobile and test through Kivy-launcher ? Also what extra i need to do while creating .apk through buildozer ?

```
from kivy.storage.redisstore import RedisStore
params = dict(host='localhost', port=6379, db=14)
store = RedisStore(params)
```

I get "ImportError: No module named redis"

Answer (score 0):

There are some general thoughts about the question:

I dont knowbif you are using Java, Python or Jiton, but probably this will be helpful.

you probably will be able to install redis library somehow - since jvm is virtual machine, I do not see any problem with that, even architecture is not x86 but Arm.

In case this library is python, it will be even simple - most redis libraries for python are "telnet" based and does not have ay C code.

However there is another, more important issue - to use redis, the server must have open, non firewalled redis port.

Also, the redis password must be inside the application. If it is Java or Jiton, it will  be not so difficult to decompile it and see the password. In case of python - once again it is much simpler - those should be clear text files.

We have similar issue with Java + Android, not with redis, but with SMS accounts - what we dit is, we asked every user to sign up his / her own account and to fill it in the application. So if you decompile, you see nothing.

**UPDATE**

In order application to connect to Redis, you will need to have Redis server running somewhere.

If your application is used in internet, the Redis server must be visible from internet.

You will probably connect to the server without SSL. This means that the Redis password will be transmitted clear text and could be visible to "bad" people, who will then be able to connect to the server and manipulate / delete the data.

From the other side, even if there is SSL, "bad" app customer can try to decompile the application and find the password. Then this "bad" customer could manipulate the data.

You also need to think what would happen if you need to change Redis password for some reason - if password is part of the application, you will need to update all users.

You probably want to do some HTTP API with end customer user/password instead of plain Redis.

Comment: Its Python +  kivy that I m using in my applicatiom

Comment: i believe comments are still relevant, just ignore java part

Comment: " server must have open, non firewalled redis port". ??? can you please go in deep or point to links  how to run server  redis server  on android and how to install it before running

Comment: I will, but prior this let me know - are you developing kind of Android Application? if so, who will be the user - trusted people , e.g. - you, your "organization" or anyone - like google play users

Comment: yes i am developing Android Application and its kind of POC project but eventually it will be a used in organization

Comment: What my understanding was redis is a in memory databse so it needed to be installed on mobile device .Correct me if wrong?

Comment: aaaah :) I totally missunderstood the question then. Redis in theory can be installed on Android, but in reality you can not install it and use it from the mobile device. You usually have Redis installed on some external server with lots of RAM. Why you need Redis on mobile device anyway? You can use Python arrays, lists, tupples, dicts etc. And finally you can save the data in sqlite. If you have Redis on mobile device, it will eat some memory and will keep it used until reboot - you do not want that...

Comment: actually i  wanted something lightweight persistant db kind of thing

Comment: didn't android have not sqlite? Redis is not good choice here for sure